# Determinar tamanho dos círculos na legenda de um gráfico do GGPLOT2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Olá!

Eu inseri esses comandos lá no R:

```
library(ggplot2)
lm_smooth <- geom_smooth(method = lm, size = 1)
qplot(percwhite, percbelowpoverty, data = midwest,
weight = popdensity, size = popdensity) + lm_smooth
```

E o R me retornou esse gráfico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém saberia me dizer como posso determinar os valores que aparecem na legenda? Por exemplo: ao invés de 4 tamanhos de círculos diferentes, eu gostaria de determinar quantos eu quisesse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar **scale_size()** para definir os tamanhos.

```
qplot(x = percwhite, y = percbelowpoverty, data = midwest,
      size = popdensity) + 
      scale_size(range = c(1,4),
             breaks = c(10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 70000),
             labels = c("10000","20000","30000", "40000", "50000","60000", "70000"),
             guide = "legend") +
      lm_smooth
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]